# Responsive Hamburger Nav Border

Tags: html, css, nav

I'm creating this navigation, learning how to develop responsive navigation menus. And I can't get the a tag in the menu to go full height leaving this 5px margin between the nav and the border when you hover over the buttons. I've spent quite some time trying to figure this out and googling, however I think I need someones help.

Notice in this image when I hover over the a link theres about 5px of margin between the bottom of the of a link and the nav. [Example of Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8CFv.png)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

a {
  color: #000;
}

.header {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
}

.header ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.header li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  border-right: 1px solid #f4f4f4;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header li a:hover,
.header .menu-btn:hover {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

.header .logo {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* menu */

.header .menu {
  clear: both;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height .2s ease-out;
}


/* menu icon */

.header .menu-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  padding: 28px 20px;
  position: relative;
  user-select: none;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon {
  background: #333;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  position: relative;
  transition: background .2s ease-out;
  width: 18px;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:before,
.header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  background: #333;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .2s ease-out;
  width: 100%;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:before {
  top: 5px;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  top: -5px;
}


/* menu btn */

.header .menu-btn {
  display: none;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu {
  max-height: 240px;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon .navicon {
  background: transparent;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon .navicon:before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon .navicon:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:before,
.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:after {
  top: 0;
}


/* 48em = 768px */

@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .header li {
    float: left;
  }
  .header li a {
    padding: 20px 30px;
  }
  .header .menu {
    clear: none;
    float: right;
    max-height: none;
  }
  .header .menu-icon {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="" class="logo">Test Navigation</a>
    <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" />
    <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn"><span class="navicon"></span></label>

    <!-- Main Navigation -->
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#work">Our Work</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#careers">Careers</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. Maybe you could make a diagram to help clarify? Where is the margin you don't want?

Comment: @Kumar Anand I've updated the post with an image showing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
 .header li a {
        display: block;
        padding: 20px 25px; /*increase the left padding by 5px */
        border-right: 1px solid #f4f4f4;
        text-decoration: none;
        }
```

Comment: What is the problem and how does your code solve it?

Comment: Code-only answers are not very reader-friendly. Also OP was asked for further clarification to which so far no one responded.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to reduce the padding of the "a" tag? If so change the padding as below -

```
.header li a {
      display: block;
      padding: 5px 5px;
      border-right: 1px solid #f4f4f4;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
```

Otherwise let us know your query clearly with a picture as what change are you expecting. It is really difficult to figure out exactly what you want..

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

a {
  color: #000;
}

.header {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
}

.header ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.header li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  border-right: 1px solid #f4f4f4;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header li a:hover,
.header .menu-btn:hover {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

.header .logo {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* menu */

.header .menu {
  clear: both;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height .2s ease-out;
}


/* menu icon */

.header .menu-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  padding: 28px 20px;
  position: relative;
  user-select: none;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon {
  background: #333;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  position: relative;
  transition: background .2s ease-out;
  width: 18px;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:before,
.header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  background: #333;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .2s ease-out;
  width: 100%;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:before {
  top: 5px;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  top: -5px;
}


/* menu btn */

.header .menu-btn {
  display: none;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu {
  max-height: 240px;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon .navicon {
  background: transparent;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon .navicon:before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon .navicon:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:before,
.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:after {
  top: 0;
}


/* 48em = 768px */

@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .header li {
    float: left;
  }
  .header li a {
    padding: 20px 30px;
  }
  .header .menu {
    clear: none;
    float: right;
    max-height: none;
  }
  .header .menu-icon {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="" class="logo">Test Navigation</a>
    <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" />
    <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn"><span class="navicon"></span></label>

    <!-- Main Navigation -->
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#work">Our Work</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#careers">Careers</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```